Getting error flutter_inappwebview has not been set while using youtube_player_flutter plugin v9.0.1
I am using youtube_player_flutter plugin version 9.0.1 to play youtube videos in my app, but it gives following error -
The following assertion was thrown building RawYoutubePlayer(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedYoutubePlayer], state: _RawYoutubePlayerState#d7415):
A platform implementation for `flutter_inappwebview` has not been set. Please ensure that an implementation of `InAppWebViewPlatform` has been set to `InAppWebViewPlatform.instance` before use. For unit testing, `InAppWebViewPlatform.instance` can be set with your own test implementation.
'package:flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface/src/in_app_webview/platform_inappwebview_widget.dart':
Failed assertion: line 202 pos 7: 'InAppWebViewPlatform.instance != null'

This is the code where I am using this plugin-
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fitness_project/models/workout.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class WorkoutDetail extends StatefulWidget{
  Workout? workout;
  WorkoutDetail({super.key,this.workout});

  @override
  WorkoutDetailState createState() => WorkoutDetailState(workout: workout);
}

class WorkoutDetailState extends State<WorkoutDetail>{
  Workout? workout;
  WorkoutDetailState({this.workout});

  YoutubePlayerController controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: 'CbggneVFrx8',
    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay:false,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
         backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
    title: Text(("Workout Details"),
    style:const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     body: Container(
         child: Center(
             child:Container(
                 child:Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
                   children: [
                     YoutubePlayer(
                       controller: controller,
                     ),
                     
                     Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                         color: Colors.white24,
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)) ),
                       height: 150,
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10,bottom: 20),
                       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right:20,top:15,bottom:15),
                       child: Column(children: [

                         Text("Steps to do this workout ",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24)),

                         Divider(color: Colors.white, indent: 10,endIndent:10  ),

                        Expanded(child: Container(
                         child:  Text("Put your hands on ground and jump ",
                             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 19)), ))

           ],)
                     )],
                 ))))
   );
  }
}


I have set minSdkVersion to 21 android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true and android gradle plugin version is 7.3.0. I am new to flutter and any help will be much appreciated.
This is my pubspec.yaml-
name: fitness_project
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.27.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^25.1.39


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/


  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages



Do you reference anywhere in your code inappwebview? Please share your main.dart file and your pubspec.yaml file.

@tomerpacific No. I do not need to reference it directly in my code. I only reference the plugin, to use it, in the above code. But I guess the plugin might be referencing it under the hood which may be causing the error. I had not used the plugin anywhere else so to keep things clean I have not shared 'main.dart' but if you think it might help, tell me and I will share it.

Did you see this issue?

@tomerpacific Yes. I was aware of this but since I was targeting and running for android, I neglected it because I thought this solution was specifically for web only. But after you mentioned it, I decided to give it a chance and now it is working fine. Have been stuck on this for 15 days in a production app though. Thanks a lot.

Adding the following script in web/index.html in the <head> section worked  (according to the issue mentioned by @tomerpacific )
<script
        type="application/javascript"
                  src="assets/packages/flutter_inappwebview_web/assets/web/web_support.js"
defer
></script>    

IMPORTANT: This script must be added even if you are not targeting/running the app for the web specifically.

@DhruvBadaya I didn't copied it. If ,incidentally, it is similar to someone else's answer  please share the link so I can modify if necessary.
